# How to define export for a module in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, reddit

Hey I am doing a small project using react-app and I 
have been trying all day to create export for [this module](https://github.com/sahilm/reddit.js/blob/master/reddit.js).

I have installed it with npm, and i want to edit it so i can import and use it in my app.js

I have tried to define "reddit" using class\function\let and use either:

```
export default
module.exports
```

And either

```
 import reddit from 'reddit.js';
 var reddit = require('reddit.js');
```

And trying to check with a simple function from the module:

```
console.log(reddit.hot('cats'));
```

But I am still getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: reddit.hot is not a function
```

I am a bit lost, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module uses window.reddit global variable. Don't override it!
So if you are on client side, just use:

```
require('reddit.js')
//...
reddit.hot('cats')
```

For server side - you have to do some trick to make it work, because on  server side you don't have 'window' global variable.

Upd:

Example of back end usage:

```
const window = {};
const r = require('./reddit.js') // You don't really use r 
const reddit = window.reddit;

reddit.hot('cats')
```

Comment: On the server-side, they can set `window = global`.

Comment: with or without
     var reddit =
?
without i am getting "Failed to compile

error  'reddit' is not defined  no-undef"
from npm start

with i am still getting reddit.hot is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Reddit does not export anything because it was mainly designed to be added as a script tag!

```
// So for CommonJS module:
require('reddit.js');

//And for ES6 modules
import 'reddit.js';
```

And you you will be able to access reddit and reddit.hot() method through the window object.

Comment: Thanks

     import 'reddit.js';

     let reddit;

     reddit= window.reddit;
     console.log(reddit.hot('cats'));


solved it.